# jquery datetime picker not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hi I am using jquery datetime picker in my laravel blade files. this is my code:

```
<link href="/blog/public/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/blog/public/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datefield').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I checked every thing but datetime picker is not working. After Inspect the page I found datetime picker is empty! like this:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

Comment: Did you notice the console for any kind of error logs?

Comment: yes I check console but no error occurred!

Comment: are you pulling this div ui-datepicker-div with ajax dinamicaly maybe.. if yes then it not gonna work, than you have to fire this `$(elem).datepicker()` after page is pulled

Comment: this div ui-datepicker-div is created by jquery. I was test it in a simple page with no ajax and something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my fault!
I manually added "hasDatepicker" class to input and this prevented jquery to show date picker.

Answer (score 0):

Dont you think you have provided the wrong `id` name

It should be

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').datepicker();
```

Comment: ui-datepicker-div is datetime picker and must has a calendar.

Comment: so where is this 'datefield' ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. datefield is in my form and I didn't write here.